# PLS-00201: identifier 'V_OUT_FILE' must be declared

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to write some strings to a txt file but it tells me that `V_OUT_FILE` must be declared but I've declared it in the declare section of the block. Any suggestions?
Here is the complete block:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY CTEST AS 'C:\Users\myUser\Desktop';
GRANT WRITE ON DIRECTORY CTEST TO PUBLIC

DECLARE
  v_out_File  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  v_out_File := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('CTEST', 'IO.txt' , 'W');

  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_out_File , 'Hi this is text file! \n');
  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_out_File , 'Hi this is line 2! \n');
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_out_File);
END;
```

Comment: What you're posted executes OK. Except you're trying to write to a directory that you've only granted read permissions on, which would throw ORA-29289 unless you're running the block as the owner (i.e. SYS).

Comment: @AlexPoole I changed it to write and still it gives the same exception

Comment: If I copy and paste the code you're posted then it completes successfully. Either you're running something different, or there's something else you haven't said. (The grant isn't executed in SQL\*Plus because there is no semicolon, but again that would give ORA-29289, not PLS-00201).

Comment: Are your machine the actual oracle server?

Comment: @AlexPoole I am connected on the sample database HR for some testing.

Comment: @JorgeCampos yes it is the server is setup on my machine and I'm using SQL Developer.

Comment: Which client are you using, and how are you running this? Oh, wait... are you also getting an ORA-00933? If you're running this in SQL Developer than it will give both errors, because the end of the declaration completes the incomplete grant...

Comment: Yes I have the same one ORA-00933

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is actually the missing semicolon at the end of the grant statement. That throws an ORA-00933, which you hadn't mentioned. Because that statement isn't ended properly, the `DECLARE` and everything up to the first semicolon, at the end of the declaration, is treated as part of that grant, which you can see in the error report (from SQL Developer):

```
Directory CTEST created.


Error starting at line : 2 in command -
GRANT WRITE ON DIRECTORY CTEST TO PUBLIC

DECLARE
  v_out_File  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE
Error report -
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

That means the nest statement starts from `BEGIN`, and actually has to `DECLARE` section as far as the compiler is concerned. Again that's shown in the error report:

```
Error starting at line : 6 in command -
BEGIN
  v_out_File := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('CTEST', 'IO.txt' , 'W');

  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_out_File , 'Hi this is text file! \n');
  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_out_File , 'Hi this is line 2! \n');
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_out_File);
END;
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 2, column 3:
PLS-00201: identifier 'V_OUT_FILE' must be declared
...
```

If you add the missing semicolon then it works:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY CTEST AS 'C:\Users\myUser\Desktop';
GRANT WRITE ON DIRECTORY CTEST TO PUBLIC;

DECLARE
  v_out_File  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;
BEGIN
  v_out_File := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('CTEST', 'IO.txt' , 'W');

  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_out_File , 'Hi this is text file! \n');
  UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(v_out_File , 'Hi this is line 2! \n');
  UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(v_out_File);
END;
/
```

which gets

```
Directory CTEST created.


Grant succeeded.


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: great answer u solved the problem but I can't access any directory in the windows file system can you help?

Comment: I don't do much on Windows. I suspect whatever credentials the Oracle service is running under just can't access your personal home directory's desktop folder. Can you change it to a more public folder and see if it's happier?

Comment: I tried to access a folder in the D drive but my access was denied too

Comment: Do you get an error from the create? If you're connected as HR I wouldn't have thought you'd have privileges to create a directory object at all.

Comment: Yeah that's it I want to grant the HR this privilege

Comment: A user can't grant privileges to themselves. You'd usually create the directory as SYS, and then also grant the read/write/execute directory privileges to HR (not public) as SYS as well, as a one-off action.